# Why is the geometry package messing my margins up?

Tags: margins, geometry

I want to write a document making use of as much of the page as I can. The code I am using is this (disclaimer: I took the sample text from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJjrTt8t3rAhUI1lkKHcPiAscQFjABegQIARAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.hawaii.edu%2F%7Exander%2Ffa11_321%2Flatex_document.tex&usg=AOvVaw3lVCoJozSL-6OTegeNMAAd)):

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{showframe}

%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle

\layout{}

Here is some sample text to show you what LaTeX does. 

To start a new paragraph, you need to leave a line of white space in your tex file.

To include math, you have two options. The first is called ``in line,'' and you do this by putting your math between two dollar signs (\$). For example, Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that if $p$ is a prime and $a$ is an integer such that $p \nmid a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Note that the exponent on $a$ has to go in braces (in the tex file). 

But if you really want an equation (or congruence) to stand out, then you ``display'' the math. It looks like this:
\[
    a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}.
\]
Nice, right?

Finally, we can make things look really nice for homeworks as follows:

\begin{problem}
    Let $X$ and $Y$ be blah blah blah \ldots
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Let $X$ and $Y$ be as in the previous problem. What is $Z$?
\end{problem}

Notice that LaTeX automatically numbers the problems for us. 

\end{document}
```

It looks nice, but with a lots of unused paper on the sides:
[image: No geometry]

However as soon as I uncomment the line invoking the geometry package the margins get messed up, even though I haven't even issued any command to alter them.
[image: Geometry]

I tried looking at some sources but they do not mention anything like this happening, so I would like to understand why geometry is behaving that way.

Also, if possible, some help getting the code right to leave as little unused paper space as possible.

Comment: It appears that the `showframe` and `geometry` packages don't work together partciularly well. If you drop `\usepackage{showframe}` and load `geometry` as `\usepackage[a4paper, showframe]{geometry}` you get frames that fit the actual page dimensions.

Comment: @moewe It's rather a problem with `memoir`: if I use `book` the issue doesn't show. Anyway, using the `showframe` option for `geometry` seems best.

Answer (score 1):

`memoir` has its own means of defining the page layout and its best not to use `geometry` with it. The MWE below increases the size of the textblock by decreasing the margins.

```
% memgeomprob.tex  SE 562072

\documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.8in}{*}{1.0} % set left/right margins to 0.8in
\setulmarginsandblock{1in}{*}{1.0}   % set upper/lower margins to 1in
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{showframe}

%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document}
\author{John Doe}
\maketitle

\layout{}

Here is some sample text to show you what LaTeX does. 

To start a new paragraph, you need to leave a line of white space in your tex file.

To include math, you have two options. The first is called ``in line,'' and you do this by putting your math between two dollar signs (\$). For example, Fermat's Little Theorem tells us that if $p$ is a prime and $a$ is an integer such that $p \nmid a$, then $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. Note that the exponent on $a$ has to go in braces (in the tex file). 

But if you really want an equation (or congruence) to stand out, then you ``display'' the math. It looks like this:
\[
    a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}.
\]
Nice, right?

Finally, we can make things look really nice for homeworks as follows:

\begin{problem}
    Let $X$ and $Y$ be blah blah blah \ldots
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Let $X$ and $Y$ be as in the previous problem. What is $Z$?
\end{problem}

Notice that LaTeX automatically numbers the problems for us. 

\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`> texdoc memoir`) for more information.